# How does one access (POST) arguments from nginx upload module in embedded lua/perl?

Tags: perl, file-upload, nginx, lua

I've been trying to figure out how to access the results of the nginx upload module from embedded perl (using nginx-perl) or lua (using the embedded lua module). I've only been able to find examples of how to use the module with fastcgi (or similar), something I would, if possible, like to avoid having to use.

Simply letting the upload_pass have a lua/perl content handler does not seem to work; with the body being somehow truncated to just the first line (yes, I've told it to wait for the body and made sure it's not written to a file).

At least when using Perl (I haven't tried Lua, but I'm suspecting the same thing will happen), the complete body (as raw multipart/form-data) can be made available if one does a proxy_pass to another nginx instance.

My question is threefold. Firstly is this expected behaviour/how are arguments passed from the upload module? Secondly, is it possible to access the results of the upload module without (re)parsing the multipart/form-data using a perl/lua library in the content handler.

Finally, if the latter is not possible, can I use multipart/form-data parser used by nginx/upload without manually exporting the functions and using some form of FFI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With lua you can get at normal params via methods like this:

```
ngx.req.read_body()
local inputjson = ngx.req.get_body_data()
```

For post args documented: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_post_args

Regular vars:

```
ngx.var.my_var
```

Lua nginx module has this well documented: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule

The vars that are documented for the upload module: http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

```
upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";
```

should be accessible via:

```
ngx.var.upload_field_name.path
```

Just do a log or a print on the var to verify

Comment: I'll recompile and test with lua again (playing around with the perl one at the moment and I don't have a local copy with lua), to make sure I didn't miss something last time I tried (I'm pretty sure I did try this). The documentation says "of the MIME type application/x-www-form-urlencoded", and this data should be multipart/form-data; am I missing something, is the documentation wrong or will it actually not work here?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_post_args , I'll try accessing it through ngx.var in a sec.

Comment: I've tried fiddling with it a while now, and ngx.var.file1.path (file1 being one of the fields in the form) does not exist (indeed ngx.var.file1 is null). Furthermore http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3085938 seems to suggest that it might be hard to do what I want, this way.

Comment: It is going to be null. Look at wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_post_args

Comment: I just verified that ngx.var.file1.path does not exist (where file1 is the relevant form field).